# Archive is disabled in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am able to archive the app using xamarin studio on Mac. But in Visual studio 2015 it is diabled. I have uninstalled and reinstalled whole VS2015 and xamarin. I am using windows 10 machine. Please help

Comment: Are you using iOS or Android? And why can't you just use Xamarin Studio on your Mac to archive the application? Please update your question accordingly. As it is right now, it is difficult to know how to help you due to the nature of the question

Comment: @Demitrian I'm using Xamarin iOS for visual studio 2017 under windows 7, archive and archive all are grayed out, while they are enabled for Android projects, I'm connecting to El Capitan and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I also noticed that tools->Anrdoid-> Android SDK manager was disabled too. Somehow Android sdk tools folder was empty. I copied the batch file and it works now.